# What's the proper way to modify springboot app xml configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot

As we know, Springboot alleviates developer from complex XML configuration. I have an Springboot application. After gradle build, I get a WAR file. If I unpack the WAR, I see META-INF and WEB-INF directories that include bunch of XML files.

What Springboot does is to automatically generate those XML for you. Then my question here is what's the right way to change those settings in XMLs? Since the application is built using gradle, I assume I can put my changes of settings inside build.gradle, correct? I do find some XMLs under my source code tree, am I suppose to make change there?

For an example, I have these code in my WAR in `./WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/appContext.xml`

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd"
```

I plan to add/remove the urls in `xsi:schemaLocation`. What's the right approach to do this?

Comment: do you see appContext.xml in your source code may be under resources directory?

Comment: Yes I do see that file in my source code tree. Am I suppose to directly modify this file? I wonder would Springboot override my change during the build process or not?

Comment: it is for you to modify, to configure the spring context of your application.